# How to write a function-building function in Ruby just like in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, functional-programming

I'm a Ruby beginner and currently struggling finding an appropriate way to write Functional Ruby just like how we can in JavaScript. In JavaScript, developers can write a nested function that returns a function which lets them create a more specific function from a generic function. Which looks:

```
function memberwiseOperate(opr){
    return function(array){
        return array.map(opr);
    }
}

var modBy10 = function(a){return a%10} // Make an operator function
var memberwiseModBy10 = memberwiseOperate(modBy10); // Make a specific function from the function-buildinng function
var output1 = memberwiseModBy10([11,12,13,14,15]);
var output2 = memberwiseModBy10([31,32,33]);
```

From the code above, JS developers can create a function *memberwiseModBy10* from the function *memberwiseOperate*. They can also create as many other memberwise operating functions from *memberwiseOperate* as they want to. But I find this is difficult to do the same thing in Ruby.

How can I write a function-building function in Ruby which achieves the similar functionality as JavaScript code above? Just like:

```
def memberwiseOperate(opr)
    return Proc.new{ |array| array.map(opr) } # return a new function, how?
end
```

In which I can create a function from *memberwiseOperate* just like JS lets me do like this:

```
modBy10 = Proc.new{|a| a%10}
memberwiseModBy10 = memberwiseOperat(modBy10) # Possible to create a function from a function?
output1 = memberwiseModBy10([11,12,13,14,15])
output2 = memberwiseModBy10([31,32,33])
```

Is there a possible way to achieve this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much exactly the same in Ruby. In order to more clearly see the resemblance, let's first rewrite your code into more modern ECMAScript:

```js
const memberwiseOperate = opr => array => array.map(opr);

const modBy10 = a => a % 10; // Make an operator function
const memberwiseModBy10 = memberwiseOperate(modBy10); // Make a specific function from the function-building function
const output1 = memberwiseModBy10([11, 12, 13, 14, 15]);
const output2 = memberwiseModBy10([31, 32, 33]);

console.log(output1);
```

And this is what it looks like when translated to Ruby:

```
memberwise_operate = -> opr { -> array { array.map(&opr) }}

mod_by_10 = -> a { a % 10 } # Make an operator function
memberwise_mod_by_10 = memberwise_operate.(mod_by_10) # Make a specific function from the function-building function
output1 = memberwise_mod_by_10.([11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
output2 = memberwise_mod_by_10.([31, 32, 33])

puts output1
```

As you can see, pretty much the only difference is that `Enumerable#map` takes a block argument, not a `Proc`, so we have to convert the `Proc` to a block using the unary prefix `&` operator.

Comment: This is interesting. This is indeed what I'm looking for. Much simpler than what I anticipated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I really like the ECMAScript6 fat arrow functions. They can even compete with genuinely functional languages like Scheme and Haskell in syntactic lightweightness (if that's a word … OSX doesn't seem to think it is :-D).

Comment: ECMAScript6's => is sexy. I like it too :). BTW, I look at your suggested Ruby snippet, printed the the mod_by_10.class, memberwise_mod_by_10.class and surprisingly, all are 'Proc'. Milan's answer below mentioned Ruby's -> denotes a lamba block, doesn't it? Why this ends up as 'Proc' instead?

Comment: lambdas are `Proc`s. non-lambda `Proc`s behave like blocks ("fuzzy" parameter binding semantics and `return` returns from the enclosing method), lambdas behave like methods (strict parameter binding semantics and `return` returns from the lambda), but they are both `Proc`s, distinguished only by the return value of calling `Proc#lambda?` on them.

Comment: Noted. I think I need to play around with these in order to familiarize myself with this idea.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby you can use `map` and pass a block. For instance:

```rb
array.map { |element| element % 10 }
```

or, if you prefer:

```
mod_by_10 = Proc.new { |a| a%10 }
array.map(&mod_by_10)
```

Note that there are two kinds of `map`:

`map` does not have side effects and `map!`, which has side effects.

Comment: This specifically solves my sample puzzle. However, is it possible to create a function (or block) from a block just like in JS? In which mod_by_10 is created from another generic function or block.

Comment: if I understand correctly you can do:
`def create_proc_from; Proc.new; end`. You can use this function to create a generic Proc object like: `create_proc_from { |x| x % 10 }`.

More info [here](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Proc.html).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, it's as simple as

```
 a = lambda{|x| x % 10}
 [11,12,13,14,15].map(&a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, functions are not first class citizens. You cannot pass them around. You can pass around lambdas and Procs however.

```
memberwise_operate = ->(func) { ->(array){ array.map(&func)} }
mod_by_10 = ->(a){ a % 10 }
memberwise_mod_by_10 = memberwise_operate.call(mod_by_10)
memberwise_mod_by_10.call([11,12,13,14,15]) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
memberwise_mod_by_10.call([31,32,33]) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

This, however, is not the way most people would write Ruby. Ruby is an object-orient programming language with functional elements.

```
->(param){ puts param }
```

Is the short form for:

```
lambda{|param| puts parm }
```

PS: There are two notable difference between Proc and lambda:

1. return in lambda returns to caller while return in Proc returns from calling function.
2. lambda checks number of arguments where Proc does not.

For this reasons you should default to lambda as it will provide the path with least surprise.
For a more in depth article on the matter of Procs, lambdas and blocks please read [this article](http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/what-is-the-difference-between-a-block/).